# Javascript Regex to urlify text

Tags: javascript, regex, text

In string containing a lot of following url token -

```
[http://www.someurl.com/path/to/resource/?some=params&crazy_chars=true_0_1_0_1]
```

Which I want to capture and convert to

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com/path/to/resource/?some=params&crazy_chars=true_0_1_0_1" target="_blank" class="exturl">http://www.someurl.com/path/to/resource/?some=params&crazy_chars=true_0_1_0_1</a>
```

So all the urls inside square bracket would be search and replaced by inline url to  element. Current I found Regex for URL pattern as -

```
RegExp("\[(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?\]", "gi");
```

But I am still not clear on how I can do it in single pass. Do I have to loop for till no matcher is found?

Comment: Will there be text in square brackets that isn't a url?

Comment: Yes, there are other text which are not URL in sq. bracket, like [@ID:2492395]

Comment: `http://example.iana.org/]` is a valid URL. So is `http://example.iana.org/[foo]`

Comment: Oh I didn't know it that URL can have [] as valid char. For this question, lets say the URL will not have [].

Comment: how is the url and other text delimited? Is each url and text surrounded by `[` `]` (eg. `[http://google.com][@ID:2492395]`) or is there only one set of `[]` and everything is inside that (eg. `[http://google.com @ID:2492395]`)?

Comment: Three variants exists, [@ID:342892904] or [#sometag] and [http://someurl.com/at/path/?with=params].
These can be in text multiple times, mixed up. There is no recursive [[]]

Comment: But what form is the input? For example, is this an array of strings and each string is one of the three variants or is everything together as one big string glob or something else?

Comment: Its one big string/text, which contains all these three variants in [] and any number of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Current I found Regex for URL pattern

But it was intended to be a regex literal, not a string argument to the `RegExp` constructor. All your backslashes do string-escape the following chars and have no effect in the regex. Instead, use

```
/\[(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?\]/gi
```

> But I am still not clear on how I can do it in single pass. Do I have to loop for till no matcher is found?

No, a simple [`replace` call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) will suffice. You can put a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) around the url (between the square brackets) and then use the captures in the replacement string:

```
var regex = /\[((?:ftp|http)s?:\/\/[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+(?:[\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?)\]/gi;
// here:       ^                                                                                       ^
// (the non-capturing groups are optional)
urlified = text.replace(regex, '<a href="$1" class="exturl">$1</a>');
// here:                                 ^^                 ^^
```

For more advanced replacement rules you might use the callback function parameter of `replace`.

And of course you might (should) employ the regex improvements/simplifications the other answers suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a helper function that takes a single url string as input and return the anchor tag with that url on match. Parse the big string into an array with each element matching a corresponding `[]` pair. Then it's just a matter of iterating over this array and passing it into the helper function:

```
function urlify(s)
{
  var urlpat = /\[((https?|ftp):\/\/\w+[^\]]*)\]/i;

  var matches = urlpat.exec(s);
  var anchor_url = '<a href="%1">%1</a>';
  return matches ? anchor_url.replace(/%1/g, matches[1]) : '';
}

instring = '[http://www.someurl.com/path/to/resource/?some=params&crazy_chars=true_0_1_0_1]' +
           '[@ID 65421]' +
           '[http://google.com]';

var arr = instring.match( /(\[[^\]]+\])/g );
for(var each in arr)
{
  arr[each] = urlify(arr[each]);
}
```

`arr` will contain:

```
[ '<a href="http://www.someurl.com/path/to/resource/some=params&crazy_chars=true_0_1_0_1">http://www.someurl.com/path/to/resource/?some=params&crazy_chars=true_0_1_0_1</a>',
  '',
  '<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's regex is moreless same as Java's.

The [JTexy project](http://code.google.com/p/jtexy/) (something like MarkDown, but better)
has a lot of regexes for various tasks, including 
[URL matching](http://code.google.com/p/jtexy/source/browse/trunk/core/src/main/resources/cz/dynawest/jtexy/modules/LinkModulePatterns.properties#21).

```
 #(?<=^|[\\s(\\[<:\\x17])(?:https?://|www\\.|ftp://)[0-9.$TEXY_CHAR-][/\\d$TEXY_CHAR+\\.~%&?@=_:;\\#,\\xAD-]+[/\\d$TEXY_CHAR+~%?@=_\\#]#u
```

`$TEXY_CHAR` is defined somewhere in the project.

By the way, using brackets to enclose URL isn't really a good idea, for example PHP uses `[...]` for initializing hashes, often used for checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that:

- no recursive [[]]
- no empty []
- the url never contains bracket, at sign nor sharp
- nothing else than [url], [@ID342892904], [#sometag] contains bracket

Then this simple regex will do the trick:

```
\[[^@#]+\]
```

- `\[` matches an opening bracket (symbol needs to be escaped)
- `[^@#]+` matches any character except @ and #, repeated 1 or more times
- `\]` matches a closing bracket (symbol needs to be escaped)